# get facebook subscribers numbers without access token?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to get profile subscribers(followers) number of some people, and use it at my website.
is it possible to do so without getting an access token?

i already search and found this, and according to this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app/subscriptions/ i must have the user to approve, but i wonder if there is a way to do it anyway, because this number is public.

thanks

Comment: _“because this number is public”_ – that doesn’t mean anything. Not everything that is available to a real user on facebook.com is also available via API.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're able to identify the HTML element in which the number resides, you could just fetch the DOM and look for the element's content.

Here's a [plugin example](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0):

That's not working, because you need "user_subscriptions" permission as stated here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/subscription/

You have a wrong link to the Graph API docs in your question, this is not about app subscriptions (Realtime API) I guess...

Comment: don't you think i can use the "subscriber_count" that on this link?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

all i need is the subscribers number

Comment: Well, if you only want the total number, then this should probably work. If you want to see who subscribed to whom, you'll need the subscription table...